# Java gui how to get a size of a textbox

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Hi guys/girls i am trying to make a box which will take a user input of a number. Now i have made a text field but how do i change the size of the text feild.

This is what i got so far

```
public class example extends JFrame {
    private JTextField example1;

   example() {    
        box1 = new JTextField(10);
        add(example1);
```

Now its just iam trying 2 get like a square size text feild which will allow the user to write a number in there. It will be a one diget number. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: `new JTextField(1)`, but I'd use `new JTextField(2)` to add a little extra room

Comment: Thanks  @MadProgrammer but that makes such a small box i want like a box which is like 20 by 20 box and that you can enter a number in that

Comment: um.... change the number?

Comment: The parameter for the `JTextField` constructor is the number of columns (number of characters) not pixels [according to the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

Comment: Chaning the number makes it a strip , iam trying to get a box made which is like 10 by 10.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) not JTextField.

Comment: You've been given the answer - `new JTextField(1 or 2 or 3)`. This will size the text field to hold 1 (or more) characters based on the current font. Don't try to manipulate the preferred size of the text field. Let the text field do it for you. Who cares whether is looks like a square or not. Worry about the other logic in your program and not this insignificant detail.

Comment: @camickr There is a reason i am trying to make it a specfic size so that will not help but now i have found out that i must use JTextArea so i will look that up

Comment: @TheEagle: no one said that you "must" use a JTextArea, and in fact if the field is only supposed to hold one row of text, then I would advise that you *not* use a JTextArea. Perhaps your question is difficult to answer because you're not giving us proper context for your question. What is driving your requirements? Are you trying to make a Sudoku grid? If not this, then what?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry iam trying to make a caluclater. So i am using the box to hold a number.

Comment: There is no need for a text area. I have no idea why that suggestion would have been made.

Comment: hmm Well hopefully someone post like an exaxmple and i will try it out and see how ti gose

Comment: What do you mean post an example? Just use the text field with a size of 1, if that is your requirement to hold only a single digit (although I don't understand that requirement). Concentrate on the logic of the calculator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state:

> iam trying to make a caluclater. So i am using the box to hold a number.

Most calculators that I know of don't have a small field for displaying the current number but rather they have a text component that covers the entire width of the top of their GUI, and the key to achieving this with Java Swing is in using the right layout managers and the right placement of your components. For instance, this GUI design could be solved by using a container that uses BorderLayout, and placing your display JTextField (not JTextArea) in the BorderLayout.PAGE_START position and the buttons in another JPanel held in the main container's BorderLayout.CENTER position.

For example, please look at the code in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15606426/522444). It creates a GUI that looks like so:  [image]. This shows two calculators that only differ based on the size of fonts chosen.

Key code for this is:

```
  textField.setFont(textField.getFont().deriveFont(BTN_FONT_SIZE));

  mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(gap, gap));
  mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));
  mainPanel.add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
  mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: +1, I have no idea why a calculator would hold a single digit. I mean I can add single digits in my head, I don't need a calculator for that. Now trying to add/multiply 5 digits numbers, thats a different story.

Comment: @TheEagle I [made a pastie for you](http://pastie.org/7107725). Simple code. `JTextField` has a size of 1 but I can still enter multiple characters :) and get them for calculation, also :)

Answer (score 1):

`JTextField` uses the number of characters(# of columns) rather than a pixel size. If you're looking for a text box which you can specify the size of, use `JTextArea`.

Comment: Hi there thanks very much could you please show me an exaxmple would help me out

Comment: [JTextArea Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

Comment: -1, a JTextArea does not use a number of pixel to determine its size. Its uses the same basic logic as a JTextField. You specify the row and columns and it will calculate a size taking into account the Font of the text area.

Comment: If you specified the size of a JTextArea using `setSize(...)` or even `setPreferredSize(...)` and then placed it in a JScrollPane, you'll be in for a very rude surprise if you add enough data that should make the scrollbars appear... they in fact won't.